# JQuery calls function that shouldn't be called onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Have a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3Af/25/

I have the base navigation pinned down nicely. However when I try to click any of the navigation items, the whole menu dissapears? What's that about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing

```
$('.navcontent').hide();
```

See [update 30](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3Af/30/).

[*Two minutes later...*]

Ok, I think I get it: you want to switch between both list `interior` and `exterior`. I restructured your HTML a bit (don't put `<div>`s into `<a>`s), that's why your styling is a little bit off. Then I changed the selector as Steven Lu suggested: try [update 36](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3Af/36/)

Comment: So I can switch between interior and exterior.

Comment: Please see my edit. I was not getting what you wanted to do right away.

Comment: Made another update to include the paving content and hide the columns: http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3Af/36/ - .closest() is a nice function to get from an element to the closest wrapping parent: http://jqapi.com/#p=closest

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `$('.navcontent').hide();` which hides all your `<ul>` with the class `navcontent` which is why the whole menu disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement:

```
$('#column1 a').click(function(){
    switchlist($(this));
});
```

Is matching the inside content of ALL links, causing your `switchlist` function to be fired.

You will need to wrap your top nav with a new id and change the the selector to something like

```
$('#topnav a').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `$('.navcontent').hide();` in your click handler. Just remove that and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

select direct anchor childs: $('#column1 > a').click